# Loop range, but exclude some cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range, offset

I wrote below code that works.

I want to modify this

```
Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M30:AM53"))
If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'only loop though any cells in M30:AM53
```

To not entire renge(M30:AM53) but to specific range.
Horizontally M31:O33, Q31:S33,...repeat total 7 times.
Vertically, M31:O33, M35:O37,...repeat 6 times.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim trlRed As Long, oPhoneBlue As Long, adrGreen As Long, iosGrey As Long, cmnPurple As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    trlRed = RGB(230, 37, 30)
    oPhoneBlue = RGB(126, 199, 216)
    adrGreen = RGB(61, 220, 132)
    iosGrey = RGB(162, 170, 173)
    cmnPurple = RGB(165, 154, 202)

    'firstLvValFor = Array("TRIAL", "BEGINNER", "NOVICE", "INTERMEDIATE", "ADVANCED")
    secondLvValFor = Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")

    thirdLvValFor_01 = Array("Basic", "Text", "PhoneCall", "mail", "camera")
    thirLvValFor_02 = Array("Security", "WhatsApp", "Wi-Fi")
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M30:AM53"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'only loop though any cells in M30:AM53
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value = "Session" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = trlRed

            ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "aaa" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = oPhoneBlue

            ElseIf cell.Value = "aaa" And IsError(Application.Match(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = oPhoneBlue

            ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "bbb" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = adrGreen

            ElseIf cell.Value = "bbb" And IsError(Application.Match(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = adrGreen ' I mistook following code cell.offset(0, 1) = value, this was wrong. The correct form is offset(0, 1).value. This works perfectly. 01/23/23 14:08

            ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "ccc" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = iosGrey

            ElseIf cell.Value = "ccc" And IsError(Application.Match(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, thirdLvValFor_01, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = iosGrey

            ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, thirLvValFor_02, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "ddd" And cell.Offset(0, -2).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = cmnPurple

            ElseIf cell.Value = "ddd" And IsError(Application.Match(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, thirLvValFor_02, 0)) = False And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "TRIAL" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = cmnPurple

            Else
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

To lock some cells while code is running, I have to modify range more precisely.
Inside the range(M30:AM53), I want to apply functions to non adjacent cells(range) regularly.
In this case, 1 cell above, 1 cell below, 1 cell right should be excluded.

Comment: So what are those looped cells in `Horizontally M31:O33, Q31:S33,...repeat total 7 times`  and in `Vertically, M31:O33, M35:O37,...repeat 6 times` ? Also, what is the range result (if not is nothing) of this `Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M30:AM53"))` ? wouldn't the rng is always a range with one cell (which is the target cell) ? If yes, then what does it mean to loop in rng `For Each cell In rng.Cells` ?

Answer (score 0):

The below function removes certain cells from a range, but keeps the rest of the range.

```vb
Function ExceptRange(Rng As Range, Except As Range) As Range
Dim a As Long, Confirmed() As Range
For a = 1 To Rng.Cells.Count
    If Intersect(Rng.Cells(a), Except) Is Nothing Then
        If ExceptRange Is Nothing Then
            Set ExceptRange = Rng.Cells(a)
        Else
            Set ExceptRange = Union(ExceptRange, Rng.Cells(a))
        End If
    End If
Next
End Function
```

If you call this in your sub, you can remove unwanted cells from your `rng` before the loop, so `For Each cell in Rng` automatically will skip the cells you've removed.

Comment: Thank you for ur advice.
I want modify range;Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M30:AM53"))
into these non adjacent cells (ranges) like bellow code shape.
Sub WriteNumber_v4()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 6
For j = 1 To 7
Set rng = Range("M31:O33").Offset((i - 1) * 4, (j - 1) * 4) 'change 3 to 4
rng.Value = 1
Next j
Next i
End Sub